# Java: Frame/Window between Desktop and Desktop Icons

Tags: java, windows, background, desktop

I just want to know if it is possible in Java to create a frame which is located between the desktop background and the icons on it.

Basically I try to create an "animated desktop background" in Java using Windows 7.

I found some tutorials on how to create a fully transparent window, but the problem remaining is, that this window is still in front  of the desktop icons, so its more like a "desktop foreground".

Is there a way to make this foreground to a background?
Are there other ways to achieve this in "pure" Java?

But I guess the only way realizing it with Java is native code via JNI/JNA.
Hopefully you can tell me that I'm wrong ;)

Comment: I'm fairly confident you can't do that at all. It definitely can't be done with pure Java but you *might* be able to find some sort of native library that you can use.

Comment: Depending on your goals, you could crudely emulate the desktop in front of your "background" because you have access to files via System.  Obviously not a "pretty" solution.  =)

Comment: indeed .. this would just be a "quick" and dirty solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it using Swing/AWT. Since the windows api is in c++, it is possible to call some of the functions using JNI.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I also think C/C++ is the way to achive something like this.